# Rails 5 Adding some attributes to `User` in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 5.1, I added devise for user authentication. I added some extra attributes to my table. After I create a new user via ajax User created but some attribute is missing. I checked the log, devise doesn't send these columns in the insert query.

First I added the devise_parameter_sanitizer to my application controller :

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email,:password1,:password2,:title,:phone, :first_name , :last_name, :postalcode, :address,:coordinate, :latitude, :longitude])
end
```

I added attr_accessor to my User model:

> attr_accessor :password1,:password2, :phone, :postalcode, :first_name,
>   :last_name, :address

end following code my create methods in registration controller :

```
    @user = User.new
    @user.email = params[:sign_up][:email] 
    @user.password = params[:sign_up][:password1]
    @user.password_confirmation =params[:sign_up][:password2]
    @user.phone = params[:sign_up][:phone]
    @firstname = params[:sign_up][:first_name]
    @user.first_name = @firstname
    @user.last_name = params[:sign_up][:last_name]
    @user.postalcode = params[:sign_up][:postalcode]


    @coordinate = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:sign_up][:postalcode])

    @user.coordinate = @coordinate
    @user.latitude = @coordinate[0]
    @user.longitude = @coordinate[1]
    @user.address = params[:sign_up][:address]



    @user.valid?
    if @user.errors.blank?

      @user.save
    end
```

I am seeing following log in my console :

> SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password",
>   "created_at", "updated_at", "user_role", "latitude", "longitude",
>   "coordinate") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id" 
>   [["email", "jd@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password",
>   "$2a$11$Rsn8pM0wVfiRAHwMQ/8YTeYGDn6qzAvZEFPJjqq4Ri.xZfGdof9f6"],
>   ["created_at", "2017-11-13 12:07:27.781262"], ["updated_at",
>   "2017-11-13 12:07:27.781262"], ["user_role", "t"], ["latitude",
>   53.3960084], ["longitude", -2.929237], ["coordinate", "[53.3960084, -2.929237]"]]

And why is my code save coorditanes, longitute and lattitude attributes to db and dont save first_name, last_name and address attributes?  How can I fix this?
Best

EDITED :
My js code :

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/users",
            data: {
                sign_up: {
                    first_name: $('#firstname').val(),
                    last_name: $('#lastname').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    password1: $('#password1').val(),
                    password2: $('#password2').val(),
                    postalcode: $('#postalcode').val(),
                    phone: $('#phone').val(),
                    website: $('#website').val(),
                    title: $('#title').val(),
                    address: $('#address').val(),
                }
            },
```

My User Shcema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.boolean "superadmin_role"
t.boolean "user_role"
t.string "first_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.string "phone"
t.string "post_code"
t.float "latitude"
t.float "longitude"
t.string "coordinate"
t.string "address"
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

end

EDITED 2 :
I made test with  :

```
 @u = User.create(first_name: params[:sign_up][:first_name], email: 
 params[:sign_up][:email], password: params[:sign_up][:password1])
 @u.save!
```

and de result is

> Parameters: {"sign_up"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"Onder",
>   "email"=>"Test1603@test.com", "password1"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password2"=>"[FILTERED]", "postalcode"=>"L16 2WA", "phone"=>"123456",
>   "address"=>"address"}}    (0.5ms)  BEGIN   User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT
>   1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email",
>   "test1603@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users"
>   ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES
>   ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test1603@test.com"],
>   ["encrypted_password",
>   "$2a$11$K2fQmO4GcnwH3egXLDzJr.KGERWoMR93tF9Vp7OMNxqVE7KPVKfwm"],
>   ["created_at", "2017-11-13 13:03:56.876695"], ["updated_at",
>   "2017-11-13 13:03:56.876695"]]    (0.5ms)  COMMIT    (0.0ms)  BEGIN
>   (0.5ms)  COMMIT Completed 200 OK in 218ms (Views: 0.3ms |
>   ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

Comment: You shouldn't need to set attributes one at a time like that. You can see a complete code sample in the [Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

Comment: With that said however, I can't see why your code fails. What parameters are being sent to the controller? Perhaps you have mixed up `first_name` with `firstname`, or similar? And what is your database schema? If there is no column for `users.first_name` (i.e. it's only a virtual attribute), then it cannot persist to the database.

Comment: I added my js code. I checked value in controller  :first_name and :last_name not empty.

Comment: And what about the database schema? Is `users.first_name` actually a persisted property?

Comment: I added Users parts from my shema.rb.

Comment: OK, let's cut this right down to a *minimal* reproduction example. What is `params[:sign_up][:first_name]`, inside the controller? What happens if you stick a `binding.pry` in there, and just try to create a record by: `User.create(first_name: params[:sign_up][:first_name])`?

Comment: This is the sort of question where what you really need is some generic pointers in how to debug your code, rather than a specific solution to the specific problem.

Comment: I added my test result to my question, maybe it's not a devise problem, maybe it's active record bug.

Comment: *What is `params[:sign_up][:first_name]`*? Without knowing what that is, I have no idea what result to expect.

Comment: You've posted logs, params, DB queries - but all from different tests. Do ONE test and post the params, sql and log from the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor` from your model

Comment: I need attr_accessors but I remove my db column in attr_accessor. Thanks you for your help. Now my attr_accessors is : attr_accessor :password1,:password2,:postalcode

Comment: But why don't you save postal code and password? And why do you have 2 passwords?

Comment: I won't store postal code in my db. I am using for finding coordinates.

Comment: Password1 and Password2 for second check password in backend. I will store on db only password column.

Comment: Do you mean it's like password confirmation?

Comment: yes I am checking same check and password rules check.

Comment: Devise supports confirmation check our of the box... do you really need your custom validation?

Comment: I am not sure. I am using devise for the first time. Server-side validation is my old habit. Maybe I don't need custom validation.

Comment: Devise handles all server side password validations on it's own in 'validatable' module. You don't need to care about confirmation and format except you need something really specific

Comment: Good news, I will read devise documentation more carefully. Thanks a lot.